# JSF webapp that has user specific functionality

Tags: java, security, websphere, keystore, cics

Very broad and I apologize if I have a lack of understanding but here goes:
I have a webapp that I runs in a Liberty server in a CICS region. I would like certain functionality of that app to be user specific. For example, if a user logs into the web app, I want them to only be able to perform tasks on the page depending on who they are. I've looked into setting up roles but cant quite grasp it well. I have a setup thus far where any user in my CICS with an ID and password and access to that region can use my webapp. I will post the .xml security part. If more elaboration is needed please ask me.

```
 <security-role>
    <description>All CICS auhenticated users</description>
    <role-name>cicsAllAuthenticated</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>xxx.xxxx.xxx.jdbc.web.SecurityConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx_xxxx.jdbc</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>cicsAllAuthenticated</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I'm obtaining the IDs via some SAF registry and keystore setup in the server configuration. I just need to know if there is a way to use that in Java to grant privileges. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SAF role mapping in Liberty. This will map the SAF EJBROLE to a Java EE role, which can then be used to secure applications.

The mapping of EJBROLEs to Java EE roles is controlled through the `server.xml` element `safRoleMapper`, for example, the SAF role mapper:

```
<safRoleMapper profilePattern="myprofile.%resource%.%role%" toUpperCase="true" />
```

The profile when accessing the application `myapp` with role `admin` would be:

```
myprofile.myapp.admin
```

For more information, see: [Liberty: Controlling how roles are mapped to SAF Profiles](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_SAF_rolemapper.html). By default the profilePattern is `%profilePefix%.%resource%.%role%`.

In CICS, you should have the `cicsts:security-1.0` feature installed as this will also map the CICS transaction user to the Liberty user.

For more information about configuring security in a Liberty JVM server in CICS, see: [Configuring security for a Liberty JVM server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.4.0/security/java/security_liberty.html).

To bring this back to your original question, if you use SAF EJBROLEs, you should be able to create a SAF role mapper, then use the the parts matched by `%role%` in your `web.xml` to protect resources.

You can also check access programmatically in JSPs using

```
<% if (request.isUserInRole("role")) { %>
  <!-- Content to display for users in role 'role' -->
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful.

Comment: Update for anyone who needs something similar. If you're using jsf and not servlets, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isUserInRole(role) works exactly like request.